# Is there any difference between pooled cross section and pseudo panel data?

Tags: panel-data, cross-section, pooling

I have a 17 years (1997 - 2014) of data from independents surveys. It's a large dataset (with around 1.2 million observations), which I'm using to measure the effect of distance on unemployment length.

Are pooled cross section and pseudo panel data two different things?

What I got so far: pooled cross section runs better with random effects while pseudo panel data runs with fixed effects, with is more consistent, but loose individual interpretation of results because it uses cohorts.

I'm following Wooldridge (2002) and Cameron (2005).